# Disable All Tabs In JEasy UI

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-easyui

I am using jeasy ui Tabs.
[Link To Jeasy Ui Tabs](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/tabs.php)

Is there a way to disable all tabs at once. ??

Currently  i am able to disable one by one only.

```
$('#tab').tabs('disableTab', 1);    
$('#tab').tabs('disableTab', 2);
```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Solution :

```
$('#tab').tabs('tabs').forEach(function(v,i){
     var opts=$('#tab').tabs("getTab",i).panel("options");
     opts.tab.addClass("tabs-disabled");
     opts.disabled=true;      
});
```

Second Solution:

```
$('#tab').tabs('tabs').forEach(function(v,i){
  var opts=$('#tab').tabs("disableTab",i);
});
```